# Is 'calibri.ttf' free or paid?

Tags: ios, fonts

I am going to use 'calibri.ttf' in my iOS application. 
I got this font from here [calibri font](http://www.rmtweb.co.uk/calibri-and-cambria-fonts-for-mac).
but I have no idea can I use as it is or needs to buy that font if want to use in the application.
is anyone has an idea can I use as it is(free) or I need to approve their licesnse. also, I didn't found their licenses.

Comment: The link you posted reads "These fonts are copyrighted to Microsoft, however (I have checked with Microsoft UK on this by telephone on 14th June 2013) you are allowed to have them provided that you own a copy of either:

– Microsoft PowerPoint Viewer (Free), fonts are included

– Microsoft Office (Any version, Windows or Mac)"

Comment: This is not a "code doesn't work" or even general programming question for Stackoverflow, this is a question about typeface licensing, which you should be asking in a more appropriate place like http://typedrawers.com ... **after** you find the *trivially easily located* homepage for the Calibiri font, read through the legal information there, and somehow find that information unclear.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about pricing/licensing, and not about programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not a free font. You'd have to licence it from Ascender Corporation to distribute it with an app.

A good option would be going with [Carlito](https://fontlibrary.org/en/font/carlito) which was designed by Google and released for free. It's metric-compatible with Calibri (meaning it'll take up the same vertical and horizontal space for a given size) and looks quite similar.

Answer (score 0):

Is Calibri Free to Use? No, you cannot use this typeface in free-to-use projects. You have to buy a license from any of the popular font services to use it. (Posted 20 February 2017)